# Overvolting a brushed DC motor

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, motor, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter

I have an air pump that takes 6 volt at 40 watt. Unfortunately at this power and such a low voltage it is very hard to find a portable power supply other than a battery. I have a 12 volt battery, and if I'm right, its going to take in 80 watts. Well, its wiring is made from solid metal, and even that is extremely hot for a few seconds after the motor is switched off. The only way currently to run it is with the D cells, but they aren't rechargeable and I'm worried they will run out. I tried other methods, with my 6 volt NiCd battery the wires smoked, and with my power bank it registered as a short and it cut power.

tl;dr Can I run this motor at 12 volts instead of the native 6 volts?

Comment: "portable power source other than a battery" <- What did you want to use, alternatively?

Comment: and to answer your final question *Can I run this motor at 12 volts instead of the native 6 volts?* We can't tell you, because we don't even know the model of that motor. I'd expect that the answer is "no", but really, without more info, this can't be answered.

Comment: At 12V there is likely twice the current at twice the voltage hence 4 times the power.

Comment: Not to mention that a brushed DC motor will run at twice the speed when supplied with twice the voltage.

Comment: "with my 6 volt NiCd battery it smoked," if it did that with what fits your description of its designed supply, you should probably stop trying to use it at all.

Comment: Assuming the motor has not yet been destroyed, you could try powering it from a 6 V battery charger rated at 8 amps or more: car battery chargers sometimes have a 6/12 V switch so that they can be used to charge motorcycle batteries.

Comment: Pay attention to Chris Stratton. Go to YouTube and watch the Monty Python "Dead Parrot" skit. Now consider the phrase, "This is an ex motor". Almost any NiCd battery will provide the necessary current, so the fact that the motor smoked with that battery is pretty definitive. A different power supply simply will not help. And you should consider that smoking is not a characteristic of a motor which is dissipating too little power.

Comment: Did the motor smoke with the 6 volt NiCd battery or was it the battery that smoked?

Comment: The wires smoked, not the motor or battery

Comment: It doesn't matter what smoked, you still should not subject this setup to that again.  If that happened when you applied 6v from a low-impedance supply, then it means that this system **is not suitable for use with 6v**, but rather either needs some **unknown other** supply, or is more simply faulty.

Comment: Actually it is designed for 6 volt, however it takes 7 amperes which makes the wires very hot. Also the wires were very thin, less than 1/16th of an inch

Comment: Again, **if they smoked, it is *not* designed for this voltage**.  Not everything is intended for a voltage-mode supply. It may assume current limiting behavior from internal impedance in the original power source, or it may just be a defective product.  This just isn't the motor you want to be trying to use with a different type of power supply - try finding a small car vacuum cleaner to adapt or something like that.

Comment: Well, I'm planning to make my own blower instead of that, and this question is already marked as solved. Also, for clarification, it **did** use batteries, and it used constant voltage one, and they were replaceable by any other D cell battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's 7A, which is quite inconvenient, and probably more at startup. As the comments say, you can't run it at 12V without some sort of conversion or current limit (which will in practice reduce the voltage).

I'd try a R/C model powerpack with a nominal voltage of 7.2V. That's only a small overvoltage and will 'sag' in use. You should get one with at least 5000mAh and at least 10C to be sure. [A random example;](http://www.modelsport.co.uk/overlander-supersport-7.4v-5000mah-30c-lipo-pack-no-con.-/rc-car-products/378702) that one is quoted as 37WH, so it should last most of an hour, say 35-45min.

Comment: I can't buy a new battery, but I found a 6 volt lead-acid battery from an emergency light laying around. I'm going to try using that.

Answer (score 3):

**If the voltage is increased by even one volt, there is a strong possibility that the motor and/or the pump may overheat or be damaged in some other manner.**

Any increase in voltage will mean a proportional increase in speed. Depending on the air pump design, operating at a higher speed may require anything between the same torque and a lot more torque. If it requires any more torque, that will overload the motor and draw more current. The motor may have some capability to deliver more than its rated power at increased speed with no increase in torque, but there will be some increased losses causing the motor to overheat. The losses in the air pump will also increase with any increase in speed. That could cause overheating and damage.

Answer (score 1):

Such a big discussion and not a single mention of Ohms Law

```
Current[Amps] = Voltage[Volts] / Resistance[Ohms]
```

Measure the internal resistance of your DC motor with a digital multimeter. Plug in the values and you can find out how much current your motor will draw at any voltage.

**Calculations**

Because don't have the specs and I can't measure the resistance I am going to use this handy formula instead

```
Power[Watts] = Votage[Volts] x Current[Amps]
```

Plugging in the values

```
40[W] = 6.0[V] x {some amount of current}[A]
```

Punching the numbers into calculator yields 6.67 Amps. Internal resistance is calculated at 0.89 Ohms. *That is a short circuit right there, no way this motor can be rated at 40 Watts. Quick Google search does not yield a single 6V DC 40 Watt motors.*

If you wish to bump up the voltage from 6V to 12V and stay within the same temps you will need to reduce the current draw.

Plugging in the values

```
40[W] = 12.0[V] x {some amount of current}[A]
```

Provided you can limit the current draw to 3.34 Amps the motor will not even know the difference.

**Conclusion**

You will need a pretty sophisticated 12V power supply that can regulate current output.

All that aside if the motor is overheating it is drawing too much current. Either due to the load (motor is working too hard) or increased internal resistance.

**Some suggestions**

1. Take the motor apart (if possible) and clean the commutator of any carbon build up from the brushes. At the same time inspect the condition of your brushes, commutator and internal resistance in the windings (basic electric motor maintenance).
2. Somehow improve air flow to the motor.
3. Or simply allows the motor to free spin for a short period of time when it gets too hot.

**Alternative solutions**

What you're describing is common enough problem in an electric bike, scooter, vehicle community. Where the supply voltage is usually higher than the component is rated for.

One very common problem is ebike lights. They are usually rated to 12V dc but your supply might be 48V because that's what you need to drive the motor.

One common solution in this instance is to put more than one load in series to make up the voltage. Example 4 lights at 12V each will amount to 48V.

A more expensive solution is to get DC/DC converter that will step down the voltage. Some of the more expensive lights have a built in DC/DC converter.

Answer (score 0):

The motor starting current will be based on its DCR and applied voltage which will drop to the rated current, depending if it is rated for a 6V lead acid battery or exactly 6.0V.

In order for the battery to be cool with a 40W load, it's internal ESR must be <= 2% of the motor ESR (DCR ) This implies a large Ah capacity and good condition and state of charge (SoC).

Without a motor spec, you can compute the power dissipated from various sources and choose the best match for your load.

I would consider a PWM switch with a 20A rating and 7.4V LiPo pack with charger attached to drive at 6V average with a fixed pot setting or a series limit on PWM.

Comment: It's rated for 4 D cell batteies and they overload every single supply I tried other than the D cell batteries. I can't use a PWM, because it'd be cheaper to get a 12v to 6v converter